# See headers of dead letter queue

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using JDBC sink connector to load data from kafka topic to postgres.
here is my configuration

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8083/connectors/customer_sink_1/config' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
 "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
 "connection.user":"user",
 "connection.password":"passwd",
 "tasks.max" : "1",
 "topics":"table_name_same_as_topic_name",
 "insert.mode":"insert",
  "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
 "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "quote.sql.identifiers":"never",
 "errors.tolerance":"all",
 "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"failed_records",
 "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor":"1",
 "errors.log.enable":"true",
 "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable":"true",
 "reporter.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
 "reporter.result.topic.name":"success-responses",
 "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor":"1",
"reporter.error.topic.name":"error-responses",
"reporter.error.topic.replication.factor":"1"
}'
```

I downloaded kafka from [apache kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) on windows and using `.bat` files to use the service.

I was able to send the failed records to other topic but when I tried consuming it using kafka-consumer from command line was not able to see the headers, but can see the data/record which is failed.

As per the documentation, [Kafka Connect Concepts](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/concepts.html)

```
You can then use the **kcat** (formerly kafkacat) Utility to view the record header and determine why the record failed. Errors are also sent to **Connect Reporter**.
```

So I tried Connect Reporter, but the success-responses and error-responses topics were not created.

How Can I see the headers of failed records without kcat ???? is it possible??

Comment: Sure, it's possible to write your own consumer to read the headers

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer, is i'm going anywhere wrong with Connect Reporter or misunderstood about it??? why is it not creating error topics and success topics???

Comment: You may have to create the topics ahead of time? Not sure, never used that. But I thought that the reporter isn't configured on a per-connector basis, and only from Confluent, not just available from the Apache Kafka download page itself - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Kafka, you can use console consumer

```
kafka-console-consumer ... --property print.headers=true
```

Or you can write your own consumer if you cannot use `kcat`